# ☒ <- this is the only text displayed in epub on kobo

Tags: epub, calibre, kobo

Having issues with ebooks, some new ones, and some that worked perfectly before (about a week ago).

In the text sections throughout the book, I see either and only "☒" or "_☒". All images display correctly. (Example image at end of Post)

Steps taken to fix:

- I have deleted and reuploaded the ones that had worked before - didn't fix.
- I have factory reset both my Clara and Elipsa devices - didn't fix
- a suggestion from a [redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kobo/comments/115ldj3/ebook_text_display_this_character/) was to check HTML files for UTF-8 encoding, which, unless I missed something, didn't work

notes:

- epub formats
- uploaded by calibre
- tested on both KOBO Clara and KOBO Elipsa
- can not confirm any updates happened in the time frame (roughly a week)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*** FIXED, using Sigil and its Tools option "Validate StyleSheets with W3C" ***

Note: one book fixed... I will update if any fail this  fix...
Final Edit: all books fixed.